# Neo4j python binding: Querying node index for a set of values

Tags: lucene, neo4j, cypher, neo4j.py

I have a Neo4j database `graphDb` where nodes have a property `'label'`. I have a Lucene index `'my_nodes'` with key 'label' which indexes the values of node property 'label'. Now I want to retrieve nodes which have property 'label' equal to a value from a list of possible values `labellist`. To accomplish this, I wrote a Cypher query the following way:

```
cypherQ =       """START n=node:my_nodes('""" 
                   +' OR '.join(['label:'+str(i) for i in labellist]) + """')
                   RETURN n"""
result = graphDb.query(cypherQ)
```

That works fine, but I wonder whether there is a way to write a parameterized query anyhow?

I tried something like:

```
cypherQ =       """START n=node:my_nodes('label:{params}')
                   RETURN n"""
result = graphDb.query(cypherQ, params = labellist)
```

But this surely does not work, though if there is one value in labellist it works. And the neo4j tutorial does not provide much material on this issue.

Once again I am using a python binding for Neo4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is working for the whole query part of the index, so this would be

```
cypherQ =       """START n=node:my_nodes({queryParam})
               RETURN n"""
```

and you construct the query in your client code and pass it into Cypher as one parameter.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, it's worth mentioning that the `queryParam` should not include `'` at the beginning and at the end as opposed to the first option.